# video save to iphone videos folder through programming?

Tags: iphone

i want to get video from some URl,how can i get it and save it in to iphone Videos folder
with different name?any help please?

Answer (score 3):

There are two distinct APIs for downloading a file and saving to the photo (and video) album.

- [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) for file downloads
- [UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) to save a video to the photo album